# Can you create a factory-boy subfactory that only creates instances if the user requests it at call time?

Tags: python, django, factory-boy

I would like to create a subfactory that only creates instances if the user requests it at call time.

Given these models:

```py
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Member(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    group = models.ForeigKey(Group, blank=True, null=True)
```

And this factory:

```py
class MemberFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Member

    name = factory.Sequence("Member {}".format)
    group = factory.Subfactory(GroupFactory)
```

I would like the option of only creating a group if explicitly requested, but without losing all other features. In other words these should all work:

```py
MemberFactory()  # Expect group=None
MemberFactory(group=True)  # Expect group=GroupFactory()
MemberFactory(group__name="ABC")
MemberFactory(group=Group.objects.get(...))
```

Comment: Is it not an option to just set `group=None`?

Comment: It is, but the idea behind this is to not create related objects unless explicitly requested by the caller

Comment: In that case I think the only option is to remove `group` from the `MemberFactory`. If the user explicitly wants a group in the `MemberFactory`, they should do so by: `MemberFactory(group=GroupFactory())`

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in comments, you can create `MemberFactory` with `group = None`. This will generate a member without group. You can also generate a member with a `group` you specify inside of a `MemberFactory` call.

```py
# factories.py
import factory

from ..models import Member, Group


class GroupFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Group


class MemberFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    name = factory.Sequence("Member {}".format)
    group = None

    class Meta:
        model = Member
```

```py
# test_factory.py
from django.test import TestCase

from . import factories


class FactoryTestCase(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super().setUpClass()
        cls.member_without_group = factories.MemberFactory()
        cls.member_with_group = factories.MemberFactory(
            group=factories.GroupFactory()
        )

    def test_member_without_group(self):
        self.assertIsNone(self.member_without_group.group)

    def test_member_with_group(self):
        self.assertIsNotNone(self.member_with_group.group)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the proper way of doing this is using Traits, they perfectly represent 'optional' properties on a model.

```py
class MemberFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Member

    name = factory.Sequence("Member {}".format)

    class Params:
        with_group = factory.Trait(group=factory.Subfactory(GroupFactory))
```

Usage:

```py
MemberFactory(with_group=True)
```

Check out this talk for more details on using factory_boy, it's full of gems
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-C-XNHAJF-c

Comment: Corrected the code, it was factoryTrait and I've googled for this class/function, but then realized that it actually should be factory.Trait